# how to show clickable areas in a image map

Tags: javascript, image, maps

I need to make it obvious that an area is clickable in an image map. As it stand right now, the user has to scroll over the image and see the pointer turn to a finger. Is there a way to make the clickable areas more obvious thru css or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: More obvious in what way? You dont highlight a clickable image, because it would cover the image. Are you thinking like different colored regions, like you might see on a country map where each state is a different color?

Comment: I was thinking maybe on hover the area would change colors. But your suggestion would work. How would I implement that>

Comment: You would probably want to forgo the traditional image map in favor of using `canvas`. Draw your image. Have your coordinate regions, which would not only serve as your click areas, but also your highlight areas. Then it is simply a matter of writing handlers for your mouse events, ie `rollover` and `click`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a link to canvas? I don't know anything about it..